# Permission denied error when trying to make apache run Python through PHP in Linux

Tags: php, html, linux, apache, shell

I need a way to execute "python3.8 createfile.py" script on my Linux server through a web html interace. *In the future I will need it to also retrieve form data from HTML web interface to provide as arguments to the shell command, thus the method must be expandable to that, yet I am not looking for this part of the solution right now*

I am using a PHP exec_shell method, but Python throws an error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/html/ytr/output/createfile_2020-10-16_203623.txt'
```

I am running apache (httpd) on my CentOS linux VPS.

ytr/index.html

```
<! -- Version 0.10 -->
<form action="/ytr/testexec.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Open Script">
</form>
```

ytr/testexec.php

```
// version 0.10
<?php
$log = shell_exec("python3.8 /var/www/html/ytr/createfile.py");
echo "<pre>Erorr log: $log</pre>";
//header('Location: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.94/ytr/index.html?success=true');
//x's are of course real numbers.
?>
```

ytr/createfile.py

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
# version 0.10
# Maybe its going to be woring directory

scr_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/output/"
fin_name = scr_dir + "createfile_" + \
    datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S" + ".txt")

try:
    fin = open(fin_name, "w")
    fin.write("Today is " + str(datetime.now()))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

All of the files **work properly alone**. index.html is displayed properly when accessed through internet browser; when called through linux CLI, testexec.php successfully runs createfile.py, which then successfully executes (creating a file in ytr/output); manually calling "python3.8 createfile.py" in Linux CLI also works well.

When I click the "Open script" button on my page, the file does not appear in ytr/output and I get this: [error displayed on web interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbHeN.jpg)

Weirdly, there is no error message, that would be contained in $log in PHP script.

**Things I have tried**:

- Persmissions. I have given put 'apache' user in the 'web' group. Set the group of all files and folders in ytr to 'web' and given the group permissions to rwx (read write execute). For testing I have even put the other (o) permissions to rwx.
  Here is info from CLI: [lid, ls -l and getfacl CLI outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iswLX.jpg)
- Updating PHP to 7.3.23 and rebooting linux server.

Thank you in advance!

P.S. If there is another (non php) solution that could run a bash command from html, with the ability to take parameters from web interface in the future, I would be happy to use it!

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to the python interpreter?    `$log = shell_exec("/path/to/python3.8 /var/www/html/ytr/createfile.py");`

Comment: The Python script begins to run, as we can see the first print() statement returns output in the web interface, so Python starts successufly

Comment: check permissions of the log file, if you run it like you say *All of the files work properly alone* and everything worked then it would have created that log file owned by the user which would have not been www-data.. then you go and try run it with apache, and www-data doesn't own the file so can't write to it.. delete the file, allow www-data to write to the output dir and then should work

Comment: @tink I tried. Still same error

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Hey, thank for your suggestion.
I am not sure where can I find those logs. Anyways, the www-data user does not exits on my system. cls output:
[ninjatxas@brikas ytr]$ sudo usermod -a -G web www-data
[sudo] password for ninjatxas:
usermod: user 'www-data' does not exist

Comment: sorry I meant `/var/www/html/ytr/output/createfile_2020-10-16_203623.txt` not log, run `ls -la /var/www/html/ytr/output` it will give you a good idea about who owns the files

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I ran the command you provided. It seems that the files created are owned by group ninjatxas and user ninjatxas (which is my user, from which I ran the PHP script manually). How can this help me?

Comment: already said.. apache does not own the file. so when apache runs the python script its running as apache user not ninjatxas, so is permission denied (normally apache user is www-data but you can look/confirm by looking in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf for the user value). basically delete the file `createfile_2020-10-16_203623.txt` and then run it from apache again and it should work as long as apache user can write to output dir.. you can also use `chown` when you know the apache user.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I understand what you mean and even though my file name is dynamic (its a time stamp, so its always a unique file name, which means that it creates a new gfile everytime), I tested it with a static file name, making user:apache owner of the file and it still threw the same error. I am quite certain that the script is running on user apache, since I used added a few lines to the python script that print the user and group on which the script is running.

Comment: I just tested your code in apache without changing anything and it works, your right it makes a new file each time. Did you change `./output` dir permissions? It should be `drwxrwxr-x` which is 0775

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for your attempt, I figured it out myself though :)
It was caused by SELinux. It came preinstalled on my CentOS, so I had no idea there was something interfering and no one could have assumed that easily.

Comment: thats good, ruddy permissions ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it myself.
The problem was caused by SELinux.

First, see if you have SELinux on your system:

```
sestatus
```

To disable it temporarily and see if that is your problem too, run:

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

If your script worked after disabling it, consider relaxing SELinux or turning it off permanently. To turn it off permanently, you can follow [this link](https://www.tecmint.com/disable-selinux-in-centos-rhel-fedora/).

Comment: The best solution for every apache permission denied